# How to delete rows by ID in SQL Server using VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2005 with the Management Studio.
And I am new to this programming language.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Delete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Delete.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then
        MsgBox("Operation cancelled")
    Else : Try
            Dim Command As New SqlCommand
            Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=HPC-107;Database=MRPdb;integrated security=sspi;...")
            con.Open()
            Command.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM dbo.inhouse_hardware_marterfile_tbl WHERE Equip_No ='" & (Equip_No.Text) & "'"
            Command.Connection = con
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I can't get any results whenever I run it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks! :D

Comment: Probably you've got an exception. Could you try to add exception logging in your catch block?

Comment: Think very carefully about what will happen if someone enters `';DROP TABLE inhouse_hardware_marterfile_tbl;--` to your Equip_No field.

Comment: Also, not a good idea to post your sa password online.

Comment: Here's a guide to debugging in visual studio. If you debug your code you can step through and see where the problem is. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd(v=vs.80).aspx The most obvious problem is any caught errors are not reported - you don't have error handling, you have error suppression.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Private Sub Delete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Delete.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then
        MsgBox("Operation cancelled")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Using con As New SqlConnection("Server=HPC-107;Database=MRPdb;integrated security=sspi;"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand("DELETE dbo.inhouse_hardware_marterfile_tbl WHERE Equip_No = @EquipNo", con)

        'Had to guess at the column length here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EquipNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = Equip_No.Text

        con.Open()
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

This fixes a number of problems in the original code: a gaping wide sql injection vulnerability, the potential for a denial of service because connections were not guaranteed to close if an exception is thrown, and it fixes the sql syntax for the delete statement.

Comment: It doesn't still show results in my table in my database.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a SQL command with parameters.  Your code is not scrubbing the data in `Equip_No.Text`, which could lead to SQL injection.

Use SQL Profiler to see the statements being executed.  Is the delete function being called?  Is the ID wrong?  Is there an exception being thrown that you don't see because you aren't rethrowing errors?

Use a [`Using'](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheUsingStatementIsBetterThanASharpStickInTheEyeAndASqlConnectionRefactoringExample.aspx) statement to guarantee the connection is closed, even if there is an error:

```
Using con As New SqlConnection("Server=HPC-107;Database=MRPdb;integrated security=sspi;Uid=sa;Pwd=hochengtest;Trusted_Connection=no;") 
        con.Open()
        Command.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM dbo.inhouse_hardware_marterfile_tbl WHERE Equip_No ='" & (Equip_No.Text) & "'"
        Command.Connection = con
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: `DELETE * FROM ...` will result in a SQL syntax error